# Ctrl-Alt-Del doens't work in logon on VirtualBox Windows 2003 server guest by RDP

Tags: virtualbox, rdp, winlogon

When i try to access a VirtualBox Windows 2003 server guest hosted in a Google Compute Engine Debian Wheezly by any RDP, the logon screen appears and when i press Ctrl-Alt-Del task manager came up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well i found a realy nice solution. If you quickly press 5 times left shift StickyKeys will appear, then press OK and StickyKey will activate. Then you press the Ctrl Alt Del sequencially, not at the same time.

Answer (score 9):

Menu : Machine > Inser Ctrl Alt Delete . That is it! 
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Press <kbd>Right-Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>. It has to be the <kbd>Right-Crtl</kbd>, the <kbd>Left-Ctrl</kbd> does not work.

Comment: on windows keyboard its Right-Ctrl + Entf

Answer (score 3):

On the newest versions of Virtual Box the option given by [Abdennour TOUMI](https://stackoverflow.com/users/747579/abdennour-toumi) have been moved to the Input menu: Input->Keyboard->Insert Ctrl+Alt+Del which shortcut is Host+Del

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Its the same way you would delete a file in OSX, simply: cmd+backspace

This is the same as ctrl+alt+delete or whatever required on the log in screen on Win Server 2012 in Virtualbox on a OSX host.

Answer (score 0):

in sign-in page of win server you should 
first click on ' Ease of access ' icon and choose ' On-Screen Keyboard '
then click ctrl+alt+del on the keyboard that have been appeared

Answer (score 0):

I found, Host+del and then your host key might be CTrl+(left or right arrow key)+del.
I am using Windows server 2012 in Virtual box

Answer (score -1):

to do it press cntrl+Shift+Delete (right side of the keyboard)